# File upload error in graphql apollo-server

Tags: node.js, file, upload, graphql, apollo-server

I am learning graphql .I followed this article [https://dev.to/dnature/handling-file-uploads-with-apollo-server-2-0-14n7#:~:text=With%20Apollo%20Server%202.0%2C%20you,a%20cloud%20storage%20provider%20instead](https://dev.to/dnature/handling-file-uploads-with-apollo-server-2-0-14n7#:%7E:text=With%20Apollo%20Server%202.0%2C%20you,a%20cloud%20storage%20provider%20instead). for file upload using graphql apollo-server but get endless buffering for response and empty file in images folder.

I am certain error is in following two files

[mutation file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShMRZ.png)

[schema file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPDjX.png)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `graphql-upload` package using `yarn add graphql-upload`. Then you need to do some changes inside ApolloServer creation into the main server file,

```js
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    resolvers,
    uploads: false, // add this
  });
```

then you need to add `graphqlUploadExpress` middleware from `graphql-upload` inside your main server file,

```js
  app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 10000000, maxFiles: 10 }));
```

For more refer to this github issue https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/37#issuecomment-592467594